Want to give more options in an IF formula
Current formula is
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A3,2)="00",B3="Vinyl",H3="No",I3="01 - UMGI",G3="Catalogue"),"8M Block required","None")

Instead of IF B3 equals Vinyl I want to put
IF B3 = LP or 2LP or 3LP or 4LP or EP or V10 or V12 or V7 or Vinyl Box
but getting in a mess

What about this? --> =IF(AND(RIGHT(A3,2)="00",OR(B3={"LP","2LP","3LP","4LP","EP","V10",V12","V7","Vinyl Box"}),H3="No",I3="01 - UMGI",G3="Catalogue"),"8M Block required","None")

Consider using SWITCH()

Here are few ways which you can implement or make amend in your existing formulae:
Since these are the multiple conditions --> {"LP","2LP","3LP","4LP","EP","V10","V12","V7","Vinyl Box"} which you want to apply for Cell B3, if its equal to any of the values then use OR() Function and it can be applied, in some of these ways:

• Option One:
Defining in name manager as ListOfConditions
Goto Formulas Tab --> Click On Name Manager --> Click New --> Name as ListOfConditions (One can name it as per their choice) --> Scope --> Workbook --> Refers To: --> Paste the following: --> Press OK
={"LP","2LP","3LP","4LP","EP","V10","V12","V7","Vinyl Box"}


• Formula can be used as :
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A3,2)="00",OR(B3=ListOfConditions),H3="No",I3="01 - UMGI",G3="Catalogue"),"8M Block required","None")


• Option Two:
Paste the following list in some empty column in the same worksheet or in another worksheet in the same workbook, and the sheet can be hidden as well, for this example I have pasted in Column S in the same worksheet where the formula is applied. and use as
={"LP";"2LP";"3LP";"4LP";"EP";"V10";"V12";"V7";"Vinyl Box"}


• Formula can be used as :
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A4,2)="00",OR(B4=S3#),H4="No",I4="01 - UMGI",G4="Catalogue"),"8M Block required","None")


• Option Three:
Or to use the whole list within the existing formula like as below:
=IF(
    AND(
        RIGHT(
            A4,2
        ) = "00"        ,OR(
            B4 =
{ "LP", "2LP", "3LP", "4LP", "EP", "V10", "V12", "V7", "Vinyl Box"}
        ) ,H4 = "No" ,I4 = "01 - UMGI" ,G4 = "Catalogue"
    ), "8M Block required", "None"
)


Here is a screenshot of all the above:


